# How to output data from JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, for-loop

I have code:

```
r = requests.get(my_url)
d = sorted(r.json().values(), key=lambda x: x['players'], reverse=True)[0:5]
```

`d` is:

```
[{'gamemode': 'roleplay',
  'lang': 'ru',
  'maxplayers': 5000,
  'name': '[RolePlay][Voice] GTA5RP.COM | DownTown | gta5rp.com/discord',
  'peak': 1716,
  'players': 1662,
  'url': 'https://gta5rp.com/'},
 {'gamemode': 'roleplay',
  'lang': 'ru',
  'maxplayers': 5000,
  'name': '[RolePlay][Voice] GTA5RP.COM | VineWood | gta5rp.com/discord',
  'peak': 1578,
  'players': 1568,
  'url': 'https://gta5rp.com/'},
 {'gamemode': 'roleplay',
  'lang': 'ru',
  'maxplayers': 5000,
  'name': '[RolePlay][Voice] GTA5RP.COM | Eclipse | gta5rp.com/discord',
  'peak': 1489,
  'players': 1459,
  'url': 'https://gta5rp.com/'},
 {'gamemode': 'roleplay',
  'lang': 'ru',
  'maxplayers': 5000,
  'name': '[RolePlay][Voice] GTA5RP.COM | StrawBerry | gta5rp.com/discord',
  'peak': 1397,
  'players': 1389,
  'url': 'https://gta5rp.com/'},
 {'gamemode': 'roleplay',
  'lang': 'ru',
  'maxplayers': 3500,
  'name': '[RolePlay][Voice] GTA5RP.COM | Sunrise | gta5rp.com/discord [1.1]',
  'peak': 1337,
  'players': 1323,
  'url': 'https://gta5rp.com/'}]
```

How I can output data using `for` like this?

```
print('Name: ', d["name"]... etc
```

Comment: Use `d[0]["name"]` to get the first instance. `d` is a number of dicts contained within a list.

Comment: I formatted the data within your question so you can see its structure better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in d:
    print('Name: ', i["name"])
```

Answer (score 0):

d is a list of dictionaries so you can iterate on the list to get every dict and format your output:

```
for data in d:
    output = f'name: {dic["name"]}, peak: {dic["peak"]}'  # etc
    print(output)
```

result:

```
name: [RolePlay][Voice] GTA5RP.COM | DownTown | gta5rp.com/discord, peak: 1716
```